# file manager inside a MacOS application window

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I want to have a file manager inside a window. I have no idea how to do that. I don't really know what to google to figure that out. By file manager, I mean like Finder inside of the window. What would I use to do this? I'm developing for os x mavericks with xcode 5. thanks!

Comment: Couple questions: Are you talking about Open or Save panels?  When you say 'finder in a window', does that mean you want a UI similar to the finder, or have, say, a button that pops up a finder window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in control that would just magically provide a way for the user to browse the file system.

So there's (at least) two fundamental, separate tasks here:

- **Getting the file system data**
- **Displaying the file system data to the user**

You can start by learning about [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html) in the 
[**File System Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672) or in this nice [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/).
Once you've understood how the file system data is represented and retrieved via the appropriate Cocoa APIs it's time to think about how to display them.

You've mentioned *The Finder* but obviously it has a number of ways to display file system data to the user.
(plain/flat lists, drill-down lists, grids, carousel views, stacks, ...)

Assuming you'd want to go with a simple list or browser like interface you could use [NSBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsoutlineview_class/reference/reference.html) or [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTableView) to display the data to the user.

When you hit road blocks along the way it's probably a good idea to post more *specific questions* here on the site and people will be glad to help you figure out the details!